# Param tag value can't set using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, param

**MY CODE**

```
<param name="flashVars" id="flashVars" value="" />
```

How to set value in this param using javascript?

I have tried this `document.getElementById("flashVars").value="src=sam.mp4";`
but it fails.

Comment: What is `#flashVars`?

Comment: Where exactly do you set `value` attribute? In my fiddle it works: https://jsfiddle.net/5z8okrwp/

Comment: #flashVars is the param name

Comment: <object id="obj1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashfox.swf" width="620" height="450">
  <param name="movie" value="flashfox.swf" />
  <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  <param name="flashVars" id="flashVars" value="" />
 </object>   i want to set the value in this param using javascript I have tried this document.getElementById("flashVars").value="src=sam.mp4"; but it fails.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like these,

```
$(Identifier).attr('param','paramValue')
```

for your part, it looks like,

```
 $('#flashVars').attr('src','sam.mp4')
```

all these are Jquery sintax, you can use javascript like these

```
var param = document.getElementById('flashVars');

param.setAttribute('src', 'sam.mp4');
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it:

```
var el = document.getElementById('flashVars');
el.setAttribute('src', 'sam.mp4');
```

Or short

```
document.getElementById('flashVars').setAttribute('src', 'sam.mp4');
```